# What's the useful magnification for a scope with 70mm objective lens?

Tags: optics

Some of the spotting scopes which are e.g. 70mm claim to magnify terrestrial objects at 75x. But yet they cannot produce sharp and clear images at even 30x-35x.

While 90mm scopes can do a better job than them but still they stop producing clear view at higher magnification.

So, I want to know is there a formula from which I can estimate (if not accurately tell) their useful magnification at which they are able to focus objects?

I came across this:

```
Magnification = Focal length / Eye piece focal length
```

But not sure if that works for what I am asking.

Comment: Not sure if this is a question of physics. May be more a question of the optical quality of the scopes of the individual manufacturers or perhaps the motion blur of images being viewed at high-mag. Don't know anything about spotting scopes with long focal lengths but I do know that my Nikon f/2.8 AFS  70-200mm VR (the VR standing for active vibration reduction) produces crisp, clear images of distant objects even at 200mm focal length, so I doubt that the focal lengths of these spotting scopes in themselves are the issue.

Comment: What do you want to use the scope for?

Comment: Mostly for terrestrial viewing. I am interested to know  the useful magnification for "C70 Mak Mini" scope. How can I calculate its magnification? It claims to have 75x but can I know much is it able to roughly focus?

Comment: I looked up this "C70 Mak Mini". This is a spotting telescope using reflective optics. I don't think that you're going to get the image quality that you can get with a scope using refractive optics. Think the advantage of reflective optics is lighter weight and lower cost and the ability to make the front-end aperture larger for more light collection, not image quality for small scopes like this one.

Answer (score 0):

It's called Dawes limit. It is primarily used by astronomers to calculate the resolving power in arc/seconds of a telescope. "Seeing" varies greatly with atmospheric conditions, but the general rule is 50 power per inch of aperture. This is the max "useable" power that you will ever get out of the optics. It's been my experience that 30 to 40 power is a more accurate number. Aperture is the diameter of the front lens of your scope. Here's a link to a calculator that will generate a number for your optics.
http://www.astro.shoregalaxy.com/index_010.htm#3

Comment: Can't it tell until how much magnification I will be able to see the images clearly / sharp? As zooming to 75x makes the image quality dull.

Comment: Here's some more info that maybe helpful to you.http://www.rocketmime.com/astronomy/Telescope/MaximumMagnification.html